# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de la categoría padre de un producto en Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy intentando obtener el nombre de la categoría padre de un producto en Woocommerce.

He intentado con:

```
$product->get_categories();
```

Pero obtengo todas las categorías, solo necesito la padre para posteriormente realizar una validación:

```
    if($categoria_padre=="hello")
    {

    }
    else{....}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

La función `get_categories()` de WC es obsoleta:

```
public function get_categories( $sep = ', ', $before = '', $after = '' ) {
    wc_deprecated_function( 'WC_Product::get_categories', '3.0', 'wc_get_product_category_list' );
    return wc_get_product_category_list( $this->get_id(), $sep, $before, $after );
}
```

De todos modos, la nueva función (`wc_get_product_category_list`) termina usando una función standard de WP, `get_the_term_list`:

```
function wc_get_product_category_list( $product_id, $sep = ', ', $before = '', $after = '' ) {
    return get_the_term_list( $product_id, 'product_cat', $before, $sep, $after );
}
```

Con eso en mente, tendrás que usar una función de WP para buscar la(s) categoria(s) padre(s): [`get_category_parents()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents).

Las respuestas a la pregunta [Wordpress - Get Current Category Parents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3114988/1287812) proponen estas soluciones:

1. `cat_is_ancestor_of(get_cat_id('blog'), get_query_var('cat'));`
2. `$parent = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT parent FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = $category_id");`
   — *La `$category_id` se encuentra con `get_query_var`*
3. `get_category_parents($cat, FALSE, ', '));`